# Wikipedia link parsing with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract languages list from Wikipedia article: List_of_programming_languages_by_type. There are few lines:

> - [[Ada (programming language)|Ada]] (multi-purpose language)
> - [[Afnix (programming language)|Afnix]] – concurrent access to data is protected automatically (previously called ''Aleph'', but unrelated to ''Alef'')
> - [[Cilk]] – a concurrent [[C (programming language)|C]]

Almost all lines are parsed correct, except lines with multiple [[ ]] blocks (a line with Click language in the example). Parsing code:

```
for line in lines:
    lang = re.search('^\*+\s*(\[\['
                    '((?P<wiki_link>.+?)(\|))?'
                     '(?P<lang_name>.+?)' 
                     '\]\])', line)
    if lang:
        print lang.groupdict()
```

And output:

```
{'wiki_link': u'Ada (programming language)', 'lang_name': u'Ada'}
{'wiki_link': u'Afnix (programming language)', 'lang_name': u'Afnix'}
{'wiki_link': u'Cilk]] &ndash; a concurrent [[C (programming language)', 'lang_name': u'C'}
```

How can I managed with multiple [[ ]] blocks in one line?

P.S. expected results:

```
{'wiki_link': None, 'lang_name': u'Clik'}
```

Comment: Why are you using plain regex instead of a wiki markup parser?

Comment: What was your expected result?

Comment: Matt, it's just for educational reasons :)

Comment: My expected result is same with 'Ada' result, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
lang = re.search('^\*+\s*(\[\['
                '((?P<wiki_link>[^]]+?)(\|))?'
                 '(?P<lang_name>.+?)' 
                 '\]\])', line)
```

Just change `(?P<wiki_link>.+?)` to `(?P<wiki_link>[^]]+?)`.

It will not match nested structure.

```
>>> print lang.groupdict()
 {'wiki_link': None, 'lang_name': 'Cilk'}
```